# IDEs for Creating Protractor Tests

Tags: protractor

Is there such functionality for Protractor in the pipeline or can anyone point me in the direction of such an application/plugin?

I spend an awful lot of time writing E2E tests, so it would be quite useful.

I have seen "Selenium Builder" but the legacy version is not working in latest Firefox and their new fork havn't been touched in months.

Comment: Do you mean like it would allow to transform your actions on a page to Protractor code?

Comment: Yeah something like that